# Perform actions within the with helper

Tags: ember.js, htmlbars

New to Ember here. I am trying to figure out how to execute an action and the product of that action be used by the `#with` helper. Below is an example of my code:

`{{#navigation-container as |navigationContainer|}}
    {{#with (action navigationContainer.previousPage model) as |prev|}}
      {{link-to (t 'navigation.previous') (concat 'course-run.' prev.modelName) prev activeClass="o25" title=prev.title}}
    {{/with}}
  {{/navigation-container}}`

`navigation-container` is a component that exposes a few actions, one of which is `previousPage`. `previousPage` simply returns a model that I then use to create some links and use with ember-keyboard.

I'm receiving an error that the `link-to` can't build a route due to `prev` being undefined. The action is executing and returning correctly just above this `with` block, so I'm assuming the `with` block is the problem.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: it is ok to create an action with the following `{{#with (action navigationContainer.previousPage model) as |prev|}}` code snippet; but what does `prev.modelName` means? `prev` itself is a function and it contains no property called `modelName`. the action does not run by itself in the template with this declaration; you need to pass it to a component and execute it within a js file. What you are trying to achieve is confusing if not impossible if what I understood is correct. Could you tell what you are trying to achieve? Are you trying to execute the action within the template or sth. else?

Answer (score 0):

I think you understood this wrong. The `with` helper does not allow you to you execute an action. The result of `(action navigationContainer.previousPage model)` is basically a new closure function that will execute `navigationContainer.previousPage` with the first parameter `model` and the next parameters are the parameters you give to your new function.

So if you do something like `<button onclick={{action prv "bar"}}></button>` this will result in the function `navigationContainer.previousPage` to be executed with the first parameter `model` and the next `"bar"`.

If you want the result of a function in your template you have to use a computed property.